# What is the best User Experience using html/css/javascript for getting ordered inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

For example my SQL has columns 1,2,3,4,5. if the user wants to order the results by say 4,2,5 or 5,1,3,2,4 etc, how should i design my form to ask the user or whats the best way to do this?

one solution comes to mind is a select box with add/remove and up/down button. Is there a better solution?

btw the output result is in a file and not a datagrid.

Comment: You might also try asking here: http://ui.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, this looks good, will post here too. Although i got my answer(jquery ui sortable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good UI for this would be to allow the users to use the mouse to move the items around. For example look at the [sortable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) of the jQuery UI.

Comment: This is perfect thanks. one thing which stands out...its not intuitive enough, (meaning i would have to add instructions to users to drag and drop) but i still like the solution

Comment: @spiderdevil the instructions can be as simple as drag and drop to arrange list. In addition to this you can change the cursor to be a crosshair when hovering over the list items so they know what parts are sortable.